# SapUI5 getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: page1 is not defined"

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I saw similar questions but none of them did not solved mine.

Here is my page creation code in html.

```
<script>
        sap.ui.localResources("empcrud");
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
            var app = new sap.m.App("myApp");
            var page = new sap.m.Page({
                title: "Bar",
                enableScrolling: true,
                content: [new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                    height: "100%", name: "sap.viz.sample.Bar"
                })]
            })
            var page1 = sap.ui.view({initialPage:"idEmpDetails1",viewName: "empcrud.EmpDetails", type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS });
            app.addPage(page1).addPage(page);
            app.to(page1);
            app.placeAt("content");
        });

</script>
```

and its my next page function in controller

```
NextPage: function () {
                sap.ui.getCore().byId("myApp").to(page1);
},
```

I tought sap.ui.getCore returns NULL, but cant find it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have not given any ID to your app control. So change the second line like this,
 var app = new sap.m.App("myApp",{initialPage:"idEmpDetails1"});

and then try to navigate. Also in the page1 you have not given your view name, so provide view id, name, type like page.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I have added id to my app before but I pasted wrong code, my bad. 

I'll try this, thanks again.